# Add current user to entity when created

Tags: jhipster

I have created an entity with the help of the Yeoman generator. I chose not to create a DAO. The entity has a relationsship with User.

Now when I create an object I get to choose owner in a dropdown, but I would want to set owner to the currently logged on user. What's the best approach to do this?

I have tried

```
@Autowired
private Authentication authentication;
```

and

```
activity.setOwner((User) authentication.getPrincipal());
```

in the Resource Class, but this throws this exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
```

Regards
Mattias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I think all of your problem is in getting the current user.

So what make you stop from using the `your.package.security.SecurityUtils.getCurrentLogin()`?.

The above code will give you the login name. If you need either `id` or the `user` object as a whole, then you will need to fetch from DB. You can also use `UserService` to do so.

Comment: I had not seen that class, it seems to have everything I need. Thank you

Comment: It is just giving me the name of logged in user. how to get id?